# If statement and zip

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have three lists, say:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [a, b, c, d, e]

x = [1, 3, 5]
```

I want to do, with an output like:

```
for item in x:
    if item in a:
        print(zip(a[x], b))

1a
3c
5e
```

I am confused with how to print the corresponding item in `a` and the item from `b`. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
x = [1, 3, 5]

for i, j in zip(a, b):
    if i in x:
        print(f"{i}{j}")
```

or just use list comprehension:

```
[print (f"{i}{j}") for i, j in zip(a, b) if i in x]
```

output:

```
1a
3c
5e
```

If your lists are longer, though, it might be better to pre-process your data, building a dict mapping values from `a` to those of `b`:

```
d = {k:v for k, v in zip(a, b)}

for k in x:
    print('{}{}'.format(k, d[k]))

# 1a
# 3c
# 5e
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `zip` here, you can use `index`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

x = [1, 3, 5]

for v in x:
    i = a.index(v)
    if v > -1:
        print('{}{}'.format(a[i], b[i]))

# 1a
# 3c
# 5e
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Python documentation for 'zip' function: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip
You might also be interested in https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest
and https://pyformat.info/

I will do it step by step so you could understand:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
x = {1, 3, 5} # I change the type of x to set 'in' statement works much quicker with set than with list
# you can simply iterate over zip item with acces to value from a and b container:
for a_value, b_value in zip(a, b):
    if a_value in x:
        print("{}{}".format(a_value, b_value)) # you need to format data according to your needs
```